# Trying to set width and height of the window to auto

Tags: wpf, xaml, height, width

I am trying to make the width and height of the window to be auto which means it will have the width and height of all its children control combined:

My Code:

```
<Window x:Class="Read_360.ToastPopup"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ToastPopup" Width="Auto" Height="68">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorMessage"
                         TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Name="ErrorMessage" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                <Border CornerRadius="4" Width="Auto"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="4,0"
                        Background="#FF404040"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <Label Foreground="White"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Padding="4,2"
                           Margin="4"
                           FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"
                           Name="Part1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                           Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Message}" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Template="{StaticResource MyErrorMessage}" Name="Label1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I need the width and height to be the same as the `Label` which is inside the `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to set the [SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) property on your window to [WidthAndHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizetocontent.aspx) to achieve this.

Comment: thanks but now I need to get the width and height of the window after it get's sized, and the Width property and the ActualWidth property are showing the number 0, I need it in-order to calculate the position of my window and put it in the middle of the screen. thanks again.

Comment: WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" on Window should do this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set property

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

but why the height is not set to Auto?